# how i can use jquery ajax with php json

Tags: jquery, json

How I can make this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){}
});
```

but datatype json

and using it by php

please tell me an example because i tired to search in the internet

Comment: Could you please explain your question a little better?

Comment: Are you trying to post JSON data *to* the server or retrieve JSON data *from* the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `dataType` property to have a JSON response parsed into a native object:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: "", 
    data: dataString,
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false, 
    success: function(html){} 
});
```

If you're trying to post JSON data to the server, you will need [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) to convert your object into a JSON string before posting it:

```
data: { json: JSON.stringify(someObj); }
```

and in php >=5.2:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['json']);
```

Comment: this great but know what is the form of php page

Comment: @moustafa: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.  Are you asking for the php code to parse the JSON data?  If so, see the bottom of my answer.